# Creating a Mine Walker

Tags: java

I've built a small game in java where the objective is to move the player(X) to the ice cream cone(^).  These are the instructions to the game code

  Write a game where you are an X trying to get an ice cream cone in a mine field

Before the game starts, a field of mines are created.

The board has to be first initialized

There mines occupy a tenth of the board (IE (BoardSize x BoardSize)/10 = the number of mines)

The mines are randomly placed on the board.  If a space which is already occupied (either by the player, the ice cream cone, or another mine) is selected then another space must be selected until an empty space is found.

The player is placed at 0,0

The ice cream cone is placed at a random location on the board

At each turn, the player chooses to move in the X or Y direction by entering either -1, 0, or 1, where

-1 is going one space in the negative direction

1 is going one space in the positive direction (remember positive for Y is down)

0 is staying still

9 quits the game

Anything other than these values should prompt the player that they have inputted an invalid value and then not move in that direction (IE 0).

Before each turn the board is displayed indicating where the player (X) and the goal (^) are located.  Unoccupied spaces and mines are denoted by and underscore (*).  Remember mines need to be hidden so they are also underscores (*).  The board is maximum 10 spaces long and wide.

Once the player reaches the ice cream cone the player wins

If the player lands on a space with a mine they are killed and the game is over

After the game is over, the player should be prompted whether or not they  want to play again.
This is the code:

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class MineWalker {
enum Spaces {Mine,Empty,Player,IceCream};
public static final int BOARD_SIZE = 10;
public final static double MINE_PERCENT = 0.1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //The player's location
    int pX = 0;
    int pY = 0;
    //The target location
    Random r = new Random();
    int tX = r.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE);
    int tY = r.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE);
    //User input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Set up the board
    Spaces[][] board = new Spaces[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    //Initialize the board
    for(int y=0;y<board.length;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<board[y].length;x++)
        {
            board[x][y] = Spaces.Empty;
        }
    }
    board[pX][pY] = Spaces.Player;
    //Puts the goal on the board
    board[tX][tY] = Spaces.IceCream;
    int mines = (int)(BOARD_SIZE * BOARD_SIZE * MINE_PERCENT);
    System.out.println("Welcome to Mine Walker.  Get the ice cream cone and avoid the mines");
    do
    {
       int x = r.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 1) + 1; 
       int y = r.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 1) + 1;
       if(board[x][y] == Spaces.Empty)
        { 
            board[x][y] = Spaces.Mine;
            mines--;
        }
    }while(mines > 0); // set mines
    boolean gameOver = false;

    while(gameOver == false)
    {
        //Draw the board
        for (int y = 0; y < board.length ; y++ ) 
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < board[y].length ; x++ ) {
                switch(board[x][y])
                {
                case Empty:
                    System.out.print("_");
                    break;
                case Player:
                    System.out.print("X");
                    break;
                case Mine:
                    System.out.print("!");
                    break;
                case IceCream:
                    System.out.print("^");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print("?");
                break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("Enter either -1,0,1 to move in the x or 9 to quit");
        //Movement in the X direction
        int dX = keyboard.nextInt();
        //Or quit
        if(dX == 9)
        {
            System.out.println("Game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Enter either -1,0,1 to move in the y");
        //Movement in the y direction
        int dY = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Checks to see if the movement is valid
        if(dX <-1 || dX>1)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input X");
            dX = 0;
        }
        if(dY <-1 || dY>1)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input Y");
            dY = 0;
        }

        board[pX][pY] = Spaces.Empty;
        //Moves the player
        pX+=dX;
        pY+=dY;

        //Makes sure everything is still in bounds
        if(pX < 0)
        {
            pX = 0;
        }
        else if(pX>BOARD_SIZE-1)
        {
            pX = BOARD_SIZE-1;
        }
        if(pY < 0)
        {
            pY = 0;
        }
        else if(pY> BOARD_SIZE-1)
        {
            pY = BOARD_SIZE-1;
        }
        String again;
        if(board[pX][pY]==Spaces.Mine)
        {           
            System.out.println("Boom! Dead!");
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? \"Yes\" or \"No\"");  
            again = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
            {
                    gameOver = false;   
            }
            else if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
            {
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0); 
            }
        }
        if(board[pX][pY]==Spaces.IceCream)
        {
            System.out.println("You win!");
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? \"Yes\" or \"No\"");
        }
        board[pX][pY] = Spaces.Player;  
    }   
}}
```

Now what I need help on is the very bottom of the code where it says if player lands on mine and if player lands on ice cream.  I need it to loop once when the player lands on either of them and I need to ask the user to play again if they want to.  I'm not entirely sure which loop to do and am stuck on the part for replaying the game.  This is what it should read in the console if I landed on a mine

> Boom! Dead!
>   Would you like to play again?

Comment: TL;DR Please shrink your code and description down to just the bit you have a problem with,

Comment: Sorry about that.  I just wanted you guys to get the general feel of what I was tasked to do. What I'm stuck on is the text beneath the code part. @John3136

Comment: And also, I included the whole code because I need to put in a play again code and need the whole code here to figure out how to do that. @John3136

Answer (score 0):

Your board initialization code needs to be in another function. If the play wants to play again, just call the initialize function and continue the loop.

If you don't want another function here is some psuedocode.

```
public static void main() {
   bool unit = false;
   while (!gameOver)
   if (!init) {
      // your unit code
      init  = true
   } else {
      // your game code
      // if play wants to restart
      init= false
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure my professor doesn't want us to make another class because he hasn't taught that yet to the class as a whole.

Comment: Not a class, just another function like private static void init() . If you really don't want to create a second function you could move the initialization code into the while loop and include another variable "initialized" which is set to true after the unit code is called. If the player wants to play again, set unit to false.l and continue the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put everything in your main method in a loop that is always true eg:

```
public static void main(string[] args){
    while(true){

      int pX = 0;
      int pY = 0;
      //rest of you code goes here
     }
```

Its not very maintainable, but if you're using `System.exit` when the player is done it'll do the job. This is because it will basically run the entire program from the top each time you make `gameOver` true.

You will also need to mark when the player restarts the game:

```
    if(board[pX][pY]==Spaces.Mine)
    {           
        System.out.println("Boom! Dead!");
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? \"Yes\" or \"No\"");  
        again = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
        {
                //this should be true signalling the end of one game & beginning of another
                gameOver = true;   
        }
```

I'll leave it up to you to make the change for the case when the player wins.